QGIS - Exporting layers with symbology and colors to Microstation DGN format via Project Export to DXF
The final result I want to arrive to is exporting exactly what is seen of the shp file in the QGIS window view to Bentley Microstation DGN file format while retaining the same symbology that is shown in the window view (colors).
I have tried multiple methods of conversions, (by features and segregating each symbol to its own layer and shapefile, and project export from the project ribbon)
Converting to DXF works fine when viewed in ZWCAD (no discrepancies). when I open the DXF file in Microstation, some layers have noticeable differences i.e. filled areas that are supposed to be void, missing areas/polygons entirely.
I have tried the project export to DXF conversion method on multiple files and the very first time it has worked on a small file with no complex geometry, I recreated the steps for the same file 3 times and in all 3 times the desired results were achieved. (minor differences would be changing the symbology "simple fill" to having no outline/stroke style). When trying the same method on other files, results desired were not achieved
I know this may not be entirely linked to QGIS but I am trying to look at the issue from all angles.
I am using QGIS 3.36.0 desktop, ZWCAD 2023, microstation connect edition.
